# How to make the numbering of theorems as Large/non-bold/italic/Roman?

Tags: numbering, fontsize, theorems

Consider the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}


\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

The results will be as below.

[image]

As you see both `Theorem` and `1` are bold.

My question is about the possibility to modify Theorem environment to obtain the following effects:

- The numbering (and not the Theorem) becomes non-bold as below:

[image]

- The numbering (and not the Theorem) becomes italic as below

[image]

- The numbering (and not the Theorem) becomes large as below

[image]

- The numbering (and not the Theorem) becomes Roman as below

[image]

Comment: What should happen to the reference pointing to the theorem? That is, should the effect transfer to the reference as well?

Comment: @Werner Yes I would like that the same thing happens to the references.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility allowing you to independently control the font attributes for the name, the number and the eventual annotation (but I consider this to be a bad practice; the name and the number (and maybe the eventual annotation also) should use the same font attributes):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newcommand\namefont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\newcommand\numberfont{\normalfont}
\newcommand\notefont{\normalfont\itshape}

%\newcommand\numberfont{\normalfont\itshape}
%\newcommand\numberfont{\normalfont\itshape\Large}
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}% name
  {\topsep}%Space above
  {\topsep}%Space below
  {\itshape}%Body font
  {}%Indent amount 1
  {}% Theorem head font
  {.}%Punctuation after theorem head
  {.5em}%Space after theorem head 2
  {{\namefont\thmname{#1}}~{\numberfont\thmnumber{#2}}{\notefont\thmnote{ (#3)}}}%Theorem head spec
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}[An annotation]
A test theorem
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Using

```
\newcommand\namefont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\newcommand\numberfont{\normalfont\Large}
\newcommand\notefont{\normalfont\normalsize\sffamily}
```

you will now get

[image]

and with

```
\newcommand\namefont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\newcommand\numberfont{\normalfont\itshape}
\newcommand\notefont{\normalfont}

\renewcommand\thethm{\roman{thm}}
```

this

```
\begin{thm}
A test theorem
\end{thm}
```

will produce

[image]

Something as ugly as the last examples should never be used in an actual document; I just used those examples here for illustration purposes.

Comment: @Name You're welcome! Please see my updated answer (the last example code, the one containing `\renewcommand\thethm{\roman{thm}}`).

Comment: in the example with the annotation in italic, it would really be nicer if the parentheses weren't italic.  `\textup` can be used to fix that.  (an ideal "theorem font" would have italic letters but upright punctuation.  which form for the numerals is a matter for separate consideration; probably upright, since they'd mostly be used for xrefs.)